# Returning first element of a tuple after finding the tuple according to the second value in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list

I have a list of tuples that looks something like:

```
list_of_tuples = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

I want to return the first item of the tuple after finding said tuple according to the second value. I could do something like:

```
for pair in list_of_tuples:
    if pair[1] == something:
        print(pair[0])

# or

[pair[0] for pair in e1_span_sent_pairs if pair[1] == something][0]
```

but I'm wondering if there's a way I can do this without using a for loop. Thanks.

Comment: I wonder why you don't want to use for loop.Avoid for loop, you may could consider binary search(recursion).

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA binary search only applicable for sorted list

Comment: @Hridoy_089 Sure, you are right.So I mean that *may could consider*......We don't know whether the list sorted.Only OP knows that.

Comment: Take it one step further, if all the tuples are a letter and it's corrolative index, you can just calculate the key, `ord(v) - ord('a') + 1`.

Comment: I'm not particularly against using for loops, in fact that's probably what I'll resort to as it seems to be the simplest method. The code I have right now just has a lot of loops already, and so I was wondering if there actually was a built-in function for what I want. Binary search would be nice but I don't think it's worth going through the trouble of sorting the list.

Comment: `O(n)` is not bad, that's effective enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dict, so ot's reuseable, like so:

```
list_of_tuples = [(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]

d = {v: (k, v) for k, v in list_of_tuples}

print(d['a'])
print(d['c'])
```

Output:

```
(1, 'a')
(3, 'c')
```

If the `for` loop annoys you, this will result in the same `dict`:

```
d = dict(map(lambda tup: (tup[1], (tup[0], tup[1])), list_of_tuples))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really do not want loops (even not in the form of a simple list comprehension) you could do something like:

```
result = map(lambda i: i[0], filter(lambda i: i[1] == 'c', list_of_tuples))
```

But I'd just go with list comprehension and unpacking the two elements of the tuple:

```
result = [l for l ,r in list_of_tuples if r == something]
```